# How to split groupby dataframe in a given ratio?

Tags: python, pandas

In Machine learning sitution, we usually split data into trainset and testset.

for example, in a dataframe, i need to keep 70% data as trainset, the last 30% is testset.

it's easy to do in a single dataframe which i can use `df[:(len(df)*0.7)]`

but when it comes to groupby dataframe, it may fail.

what i want is split groupby dataframe into two part, first is 70% of each group, second the left 30% part. (PS. need to keep the order, 70% should be the first 70%)

let me give an example:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c','c','c','c','d','d'],
    ...:                    'B': list(range(12))}, columns=['A', 'B'])

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
    A   B
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   b   2
3   a   3
4   b   4
5   b   5
6   c   6
7   c   7
8   c   8
9   c   9
10  d  10
11  d  11

In [24]: df.groupby('A').count()
Out[24]: 
   B
A   
a  3
b  3
c  4
d  2
```

for A=='a': i should keep first (3 * 0.7 =2) element, for A=='d', i should keep first (2 * 0.7=1) element.

so, is there any good method can split the dataframe into these two part?

Comment: You may have to rework your data frame a bit to get this to work, but sklearn offers ```stratify``` in their ```train_test_split()```

Comment: Also if you're going to split your dataset manually, remember to shuffle the data before doing so.

Comment: @user14518362 For some problems, shuffling might not be a good idea. Time series prediction is an example.

Comment: You're right although if you're doing an analysis on a time serie, you probably have your length of time measurement in your data as well in which case shuffling is not so bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Pandas 1.1.0, you can use [groupby.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html). Something like this:

```
# random_state for repeatability
# remove if not needed
df.groupby('A').sample(frac=0.7, random_state=43)
test = df.drop(train.index)
```

---

**Update**: If you just want the top rows, you can do:

```
train = (df.groupby('A')
           .apply(lambda x: x.head(int(len(x) * 0.7) ) )
           .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        )
test = df.drop(train.index)
```

Or you can do lazy groupby and boolean indexing, which is a bit faster but more verbose:

```
groups = df.groupby('A')
row_nums = groups.cumcount()
sizes = groups('A').transform('size')

train = df[row_nums <= sizes * 0.7]
test = df[row_nums > sizes * 0.7]
```

Comment: does sample takes a random operation, i think i need to keep the order

Answer (score 2):

Try with `sample`

```
train = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x : x.sample(n=int(len(x)*0.7))).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
text = df.drop(train.index)
train
Out[247]: 
    A   B
0   a   0
3   a   3
2   b   2
5   b   5
6   c   6
9   c   9
10  d  10
```